# Alternate Versions of Movies

Tags: distribution, alternate-version

I am wondering when I see alternate versions of films on, for example, HBO whether the "exhibitor" has complete freedom to show what they want or the producer offers various versions and the exhibitor can choose?

Comment: Generally I'd say no. They might be slightly edited for content/length (think airline movies) but other than that...not really.

Comment: But if the exhibitor changes it, I could see the producer objecting. Would the airline movie thing be a version made by the producers?

Comment: The airline would generally supply a list of changes they would like (I believe)...these mostly revolve around, language, nudity & other such content) but they would be made by the producer. The exhibitor gets the right to show the movie they are given...not what is actually shown..barring reasonable requests. At least that's my understanding.

Comment: http://edition.cnn.com/travel/article/secrets-of-in-flight-movies/index.html

Comment: ..and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re-edited_film

Comment: Once upon a time, every movie aired on TV came with this disclaimer:  "This film has been modified from its original version. It has been formatted to fit this screen, to run in the time allotted and edited for content".  The one that does the editing varies, some producers record a clean version of the audio for public television.  Editing for time would clearly fall on TV stations, as the producers have no idea of the time constraints.

Comment: Interesting that tv station would do it. I could see director going nuts sometimes although if edited for content, usually the dub over a curse word. (I like "airhead" for "asshole.")

Comment: Movies are *sold*...if the buyer wants a custom version, why would the seller not do it. The director might have *some* rights but those are few and far between...and they value a buck too!

Comment: Movies are leased. But if the seller says, okay, you can edit it as you like, sure. I am just thinking the producers would want some control since their reputations depend on how their work is perceived.

Comment: They do have control...they can say no!

Comment: I guess they can say no but if a network affiliate chose to shorten a movie, I bet they got away with it.

Comment: It depends on the distribution deal. Some studios and some artists have sued third parties to prevent edited versions being used (eg Monty Python sued ABC to prevent them showing heavily edited episodes, studios have sued redistributors for showing censored versions of movies).